# How to backup encrypted home in encrypted form only?

Tags: security, ecryptfs

I want to backup the encrypted home of a user who might be logged in at backup time. Which directories should I backup if I want to ensure that absolutely no plaintext data can be leaked? Are the following folders always encrypted?

```
/home/user/.Private
/home/user/.ecryptfs
```

Just want to make sure that no data leaks, as the backup destination is untrustworthy.

Edit: Yes, as Lord of Time has suggested, I'd like to know which folders and/or files I need to backup if I need to store **only** encrypted content in a way that allows me to recover it later with the right passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

From reading [this](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2010/06/ecryptfs-backup-strategy.html) by the author of ecryptfs, it sounds like you want to backup `$HOME/.Private` for each user.

Answer (score 0):

They would only be encrypted if they were not mounted. As you soon as you mount them they are in a decrypted state and therefore plaintext is exposed. So the answer would be yes if your ecryptfs volumes are not mounted and no if they are.